# ¿Como inserto código CSS después de cargar una tabla?

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

Tengo un **datatables** que carga una lista, en ella hay una columna **estado**, viene de la **db** como un **boolean**, quiero colocar un botón [***como este***](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/z8b8y) dependiendo del estado que tenga. Esta parte ya la hago, el problema es que no me carga el estilo.

Asumo que el **datatables** carga primero el contenido antes que el **css**, la idea seria insertar el **css** en el **initComplete** del **datatables**. 
Pero no encuentro como insertar el css en dicha parte.

```html
this.dtOptions = {
  ajax: {
    url: this.url+'categorias/listar',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      "json": [
        {
          nombre: this.categoria.nombre
        },
        {
          status: this.categoria.status
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  columns: [
    {
      title: 'N°',
      data: 0, searchable: false, orderable: false, render: function( data, type, full, meta ){
        return meta.row+1;
      }
    },
    {
      title: 'Nombre',
      searchable: false,
      "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
        return row.nombre;
      }
    },
    {
      title: 'Estado',
      searchable: false,
      "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
        if(row.status){
          return '<div> <label id="switch"> <input type="checkbox"> <span class="slider"></span> Activo </label></div>'
        }else{
          return '<div> <label id="switch"> <input type="checkbox"> <span class="slider"></span> Inactivo </label></div>'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      title: 'Acción',
      searchable: false,
      orderable: false, 
      "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
        let boton = '';
            boton += '<div class="text-center">';
            boton += '<span class="fa fa-edit" style="color:#FFBD00;" title="Editar"></span><span class="hidden-xs"></span>';
            boton += ' ';
            boton += '<span class="fa fa-trash" style="color:#FF0000;" title="Eliminar"></span><span class="hidden-xs"></span>';
            boton += '<div>';
        return boton;
      }
    },
  ],
  order: [[1, 'asc']],
  rowCallback: (row: Node, data: any[] | Object, index: number) => {
    const self = this;
    $('td', row).unbind('click');
    $('td', row).bind('click', () => {
      self.someClickHandler(data);
    });
    return row;
  },
  initComplete: function (settings, json) {
  },
  responsive: true,
  select: true
};
```

Comment: Muestra tu configuración de datatable.

Comment: @AaronRomero listo

Answer (score 0):

En tu configuración del render agrega los tags desde el div para el switch.
Para indicar el valor es con la propiedad de checked del input.

```
"render": function ( data, type, row ) {
        let boton = '<div>';
            boton += '<label class="switch">';
            boton += '<input type="checkbox" cheked=' + data +' >';
            boton += '<span class="slider"></span>';
            boton += '</label>';
            boton += 'Switch3';
            boton += '</div>';
        return boton;
```

Y no olvides agregar la referencia de estilos del switch. 
Quien hace la parte visual del switch es este css.

```css
.switch input { 
    display:none;
}
.switch {
    display:inline-block;
    width:60px;
    height:30px;
    margin:8px;
    transform:translateY(50%);
    position:relative;
}

.slider {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    border-radius:30px;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 2px #777, 0 0 4px #777;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:4px solid transparent;
    overflow:hidden;
     transition:.4s;
}
.slider:before {
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#777;
    border-radius:30px;
    transform:translateX(-30px);
    transition:.4s;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
    transform:translateX(30px);
    background:limeGreen;
}
input:checked + .slider {
    box-shadow:0 0 0 2px limeGreen,0 0 2px limeGreen;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
    <div>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="slider"></span>
        </label>
        Switch1
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="slider"></span>
        </label>
        Switch2
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="slider"></span>
        </label>
        Switch3
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No carga el estilo.
¿ ***Y no olvides agregar la referencia de estilos del switch*** ?

Comment: También esta la referencia al estilo :/

Comment: Entonces sí todo está correcto como mencionas. Inspecciona tu HTML. Revisa cual regla le está pegando al css del switch.

Comment: Recuerdo que esto mismo me paso cuando trabajaba con **jQuery**, y llamaba una función que le daba estilo a todos los **checkbox** en el **initComplete** , desconozco como lo podría hacer en Angular.

Comment: Eso pasa debido a los selectores en tabla. Debes de asignarle algún id para que no se aplique el evento a todos.

Comment: Tampoco me funciono :/